# Make automatic page breaks ignore split cells in VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to generate automatic page breaks in VBA in Excel 2007 which ignore split cells (after merging adjacent cells)?

For instance, in the example below I would like the page break to be above row 51, not cutting through the middle of the merged cell A51-A53.

[image]

The code I have tried is:

```
workSheet.Range("A2:A" & bottomRow).PageBreak = xlPageBreakAutomatic
```

By only including column A in the range, I was hoping that it wouldn't generate a page break cutting through cells in this column.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code.

```
Sub HPageBreaks_and_MergeCells()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim NextPageBreakNumber As Long
Dim PageBreakFirstLine  As Object
Dim LineNumber As Long
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview
sh.ResetAllPageBreaks
NextPageBreakNumber = 1
While NextPageBreakNumber <= sh.HPageBreaks.Count
    Set PageBreakFirstLine = sh.HPageBreaks(NextPageBreakNumber).Location
    LineNumber = PageBreakFirstLine.Row
    If sh.Cells(LineNumber, 1).MergeCells = True Then
        Set sh.HPageBreaks(NextPageBreakNumber).Location = sh.Cells(sh.Cells(LineNumber, 1).MergeArea.Row, 1)
    End If
    NextPageBreakNumber = NextPageBreakNumber + 1
Wend
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
End Sub
```